# Github/Pycharm integration

Tags: github, pycharm

So for my computer science class I have to do my final project with GitHub in PyCharm. Apparently I just have to make a GitHub account (I did) and then go into the PyCharm menu/startup thing and click "check out from version control" and then "GitHub" [as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vej9r.png). However, this just returns the error here:

Cannot run program "git.exe": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

This makes sense since my PyCharm and my GitHub account aren't linked in any way, but my computer science lesson doesn't list anything to do other than create an account and then open up GitHub in PyCharm. Do I need to download something? If so, what? Or is there a way to "log in" to GitHub in PyCharm? Then again, according to the lesson that comes in a later step, something about a clone repository where you can insert the URL of the project.

So: anything that causes the error, how I can fix it, etc. would be extremely helpful. I'm kind of new to computer science, though; this is only my second class. Sorry if this is something simple I'm missing.

Comment: You have to install Git.

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot run program "git.exe": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

The message says that "git.exe" file cannot be found. This is because you don't have Git installed.

I suggest you to install the [Git for Windows](https://git-for-windows.github.io/) package.

After that PyCharm should detect where "git.exe" is. If not, I assume there should be an option where you can specify the path to "git.exe".

Comment: Ah, thank you! I assumed I needed to download something, but the lesson didn't mention it so I wasn't sure what version to get, or if I should get one at all.